# Objective-c going down / up with acceleration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caanimation

Im trying to make an animation of falling object that goes up when you touch the screen. That is not a problem if i want to use a linear velocity for this object, but i would better like it if it accelerated towards ground and when user touches screen it starts accelerating to the opposite direction. So lets suppose we have an object that goes 10px/s towards ground and when user touches screen i want it to have a = -5px/s^2 which means that even after touching screen, the object would still go down for another 2 seconds. Any idea how to do this in a "nice way" (right now im rewriting UIImageViews.frame every time with new CGRect but thats not really good way to do it i guess)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can always use UIView animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                          delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                              // put the co-ordinates you want your object to FINISH on in here
                          } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
```

Comment: Thats the problem - i dont really know the final coordinates at the beginning - i know them only when user touches screen - which might be somewhere in the middle of animation

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to do this in a "nice way" (right now im rewriting
>   UIImageViews.frame every time with new CGRect but thats not really
>   good way to do it i guess)?

Use [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004627-SW1). It's very easy to get started, and very powerful once you've gotten started. You can specify your own timing function, so you can give the appearance of acceleration. There's no reason for you to redraw your image view manually... Core Animation will do this for you more easily, and better.